# Show only features within current Atlas feature in legend

Tags: qgis, legend, atlas

I want to create a atlas showing in the legend only the layer that is displayed on that page.

There are two options for the legend item:

- only show items inside linked map
- only show items inside current report feature

The first one shortens the legend to the layers in the same theme, but I suppose I have to tick the second as well.
The second doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the second option does work. But you can always edit your legend manually. Simply check off the box refresh automatically in your legend item properties.

Comment: In an atlas-layout I have multiple extents (30) and for each extent 5 layers overlaying each other (rasters). So manually adjusting the legend is not an option.
I iterate over the extents and to view the different layers in a different map I use Themes. I would like to create a Theme for the same layer for all the extents. This works fine for the maps, but not for the legend.